# Join two tables with different number of rows on power BI using DAX

Tags: join, merge, powerbi, dax

I have two tables on Power BI which I want join on the date:

This is the table 1 (NewTable_Class):

[image]

And this is the table 2 (NewTable_Date):

[image]

Make this on the query editor is simple but I can not use that because it messed up with some requirements of the project, so I have to use DAX expression for this.

```
Tabla = UNION(NewTable_Class;NewTable_Date)
```

But it generates an error, saying that the number of rows have to be the same on both tables. Is there any equivalent of a regular join on DAX for power BI?

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to **join** (merge) these two tables on date (btw I don't see a date columns in your screenshots), while you are trying to **append** (union) them. Which one is true? Since the tables has different number of columns, I believe you actually want to join them together and get a new table with more columns.

[UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/union-function-dax) appends the rows from both tables and returns a table with the same columns, but more rows. That's why obviously it [requires](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/union-function-dax#remarks) both tables to have the same number of columns.

You can use [NATURALINNERJOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/naturalinnerjoin-function-dax) or [NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/naturalleftouterjoin-function-dax):

```
Tabla = NATURALINNERJOIN(NewTable_Class;NewTable_Date)
```

Comment: The date column is in date format, when I put that variable into a wiget is automatically splited into: Año, Mes and Dia. But in the original tables it is date on both tables.